# Swift Package Manager cannot find header file

Tags: c, swift, swift-package-manager

I have the following project structure:

```bash
.
├── Package.swift
├── Sources
│   └── Argon
│       ├── include
│       │   └── Argon.h
│       └── some_source.c
└── deps
    └── olive.c
        └── olive.c # Header file
```

Contents op Package.swift:

```swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.7
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "MyPackage",
  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "Argon",
      cSettings: [
        .headerSearchPath("deps/olive.c"),
      ]
    )
  ]
)
```

Argon.h contains the follwing include:

```c
#include <olive.c>
```

When I run `swift build`, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /Users/jonaseveraert/Documents/projects/photobooth/Sources/Argon/some_source.c:3:
/Users/jonaseveraert/Documents/projects/photobooth/Sources/Argon/src/../include/argon.h:41:10: fatal error: 'olive.c' file not found
#include <olive.c>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

It looks to me that the `headerSearchPath` is not working.

I have tried with `.unsafeFlags(["-Idep/olive.c"])`, but did not work.

I tried renaming olive.c to olive.h, did not work.

Anyone have any pointers on why this happens?

(yes, the header file ends with a .c extension, that's how the library creatorr named it)

Comment: You used `-Idep/olive.c`. But, in your hierarchy, the directory is `deps` [_not_ `dep`]. Also, for include search, generally, we want the containing _directory_ (not the file). So, have you tried `-Ideps` (or `-I/full/path/to/deps`). Also, similar for: `.headerSearchPath("deps")`

Comment: @CraigEstey My bad, the `dep` was a typo, it shuld be `deps`. It should be `-Ideps/olive.c` though, as the olive.c header is inside of the `deps/olive.c` directory. So, it's  still giving me the same error.

Comment: Okay, I'll close my eyes and ignore the screwy names that the tool is generating. _Side note:_ Nothing prevents you from writing a wrapper script that invokes the `swift build` and then renames a few things (a project for later?). But, you may need the _full_ path to the directory (e.g. `.headerSearchPath("/Users/jonaseveraert/Documents/projects/photobooth/Sources/deps/olive.c")`. You could run `swift build` under `strace` to see the syscalls it uses (i.e. the files it tries to open). This is what I use to debug a similar "path search" issue

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you for your help, strace doesn't seem to be available on mac, but I debugged with `swift build -vv`. It seems cSettings aren't applied to the "umbrelle headers". Instead, I did: `swift run -Xcc -Ipath/to/header`, which worked

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. The macos equivalent of `strace` is `dtruss`